# WMQ using PCFAgent throws exception

Tags: exception, ibm-mq

i am trying to send PCF message to MQ by PCFMessageAgent  class, like this

```
PCFMessageAgent agent = new PCFMessageAgent();
agent.setCheckResponses(false);
agent.connect(QueueManager);
```

but getting:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:    
                               com/ibm/mq/internal/MQCommonServices
```

i have noticed that the parent of PCFMessageAgent is PCAgent that has static method :

```
 public static JmqiEnvironment getJmqiEnv() {
    return MQCommonServices.jmqiEnv;
}
```

this PCAgent is called by the PCFMessageAgent constructor, so the classLoader try to load this class and then throw this exception. the reason is that MQCommonServices is not define anywhere. what is this class\variable
how can i get it work?

Answer (score 0):

You did not include all of the required MQ JAR files.  The MQCommonServices class is located in the 'com.ibm.mq.jar' file.